# Using svn_wc in jruby rake task for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, svn, jruby

I am trying to write a rake task in my Ruby on rails project to do checkout from my SVN repository.

I used svn_wc gem file but i get the following error:

```
LoadError: no such file to load -- svn/core
```

I am using Windows PC. Pls suggest me steps to write a rake task for windows environment using this gem

Or

Is there any alternative gem file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

svn_wc requires the svn ruby bindings -- I'd install the windows svn command line and language bindings http://sourceforge.net/projects/win32svn/files/1.7.4/

That being said I don't know if those bindings work with Jruby